# Test Eclipse JDT refactoring

Tags: unit-testing, testing, eclipse-plugin, refactoring, eclipse-jdt

What is the best way to **unit test** a JDT Eclipse plugin which performs **LTK refactorings?** Do any helper classes exist for this purpose?

My plugin contains a class which extends `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.Refactoring` and implements the methods `checkInitialConditions(...)`, `checkFinalConditions(...)` and `createChange(...)`. Moreover, I have classes implementing `RefactoringContribution` and `RefactoringDescriptor`.

However, I don't know where my tests should hook in. How can I start the refactoring from the code?